# cannot import name '_version' from partially initialized module 'PIL'

Tags: moviepy

im trying to use moviepys text clip function and i keep getting this exception thrown

cannot import name '*version' from partially initialized module 'PIL' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Grawlix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL_*init**.py)

ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling pil, installing different versions. nothings quite working. any advice?

heres the code thats getting the error

```
import os
import random
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, clips_array, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip

text = f"Part {i + 1}"
txt_clip = TextClip(text, fontsize=70, color='white', bg_color='black')
txt_clip = txt_clip.set_position(('center', 'bottom')).set_duration(segment.duration)
final_video = final_video.set_duration(segment.duration)
final_video = final_video.set_audio(None).set_video_params(append_images=[txt_clip.img])
```

i was trying to get my robot to add text to video but it gets interrupted by this error

```
TRACEBACK:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\CodingStuff\EvilProject\EvilProject\EvilProject.py", line 78, in <module>
    txt_clip = TextClip(text, fontsize=70, color='white', bg_color='black')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1148, in __init__
    ImageClip.__init__(self, tempfilename, transparent=transparent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 889, in __init__
    img = imread(img)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\__init__.py", line 97, in imread
    return imread_v2(uri, format=format, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\v2.py", line 359, in imread
    with imopen(uri, "ri", **imopen_args) as file:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\imopen.py", line 196, in imopen
    plugin_instance = candidate_plugin(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\config\plugins.py", line 107, in partial_legacy_plugin
    return LegacyPlugin(request, legacy_plugin)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\legacy_plugin_wrapper.py", line 80, in __init__
    if not self._format.can_read(request):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\format.py", line 242, in can_read
    return self._can_read(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow_legacy.py", line 263, in _can_read
    Image = self._init_pillow()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow_legacy.py", line 243, in _init_pillow
    import PIL
  File "C:\Users\Grawlix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import _version
ImportError: cannot import name '_version' from partially initialized module 'PIL' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Grawlix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

Comment: can you please include the full error traceback?